# Keras custom non-trainable layer for switching input; "An operation has `None` for gradient"

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm having an issue when attempting to implement a custom "switch" layer in Keras (Tensorflow backend). This layer takes 3 inputs: the first two inputs are images, and the third is some data that can be used to make a determination of which of the first two inputs to use and then passes that input on to the next layer unchanged.

Inserting this layer into a model, everything compiles without issue, but when I go to fit the model I get the following message:

> ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.

I've isolated the issue to the inclusion of this custom layer in my model; if I leave the layer out, I am able to train (although the second and third inputs are not used as this is the only layer into which they are input).

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.engine.topology import Layer

class SwitchLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(SwitchLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(SwitchLayer, self).build(input_shape)
        self.trainable = False


    def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
        img_one = inputs[0]
        img_two = inputs[1]


        if (np.array(inputs[2]) == np.array([1, 0])).all():
            return img_one
        return img_two
```

Interestingly, if I just return `img_one` or `img_two` without performing the check, everything works (but, of course, I lose out on the desired switching).

Comment: Do the switching with K.switch, or K.equal and other functions from the backend. (`import keras.backend as K`)

Comment: thanks; K.switch was the right approach here. I changed the third input to a boolean tensor, and just used that: `return K.switch(inputs[2], inputs[0], inputs[1])`